# How does the Properties Pattern work?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

I'm referring to the pattern (aka Universal Design Pattern) as discussed in this blog post

[Universal Design pattern](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.ca/2008/10/universal-design-pattern.html)

I guess I'm not entirely clear how to use this in practice.  And how it works to accomplish operations or tasks.

In particular regarding this explanation

> It's the core API for any collection that maps names to values:
>
> ```
> get(name)
> put(name, value)
> has(name)
> remove(name)
> ```
>
> There are typically also ways to iterate over the properties, optionally with a filter of some sort.

Are the keys the name? And what are the values?

And how do you perform operations?  Where are instructions for performing tasks and operations on data stored? and how are they called?  Are the embedded into the 'values' as classes?

Comment: It seems that the "Universal Design Pattern" may refer to different subject than the "Properties Pattern"

Comment: @umlcat No I think the author of that blog is referring to them both to mean the same type of pattern. He just calls it universal because it appears everywhere.

Comment: Note that this is technically an anti-pattern - it's an implementation of dynamic typing, and even the author of the blog post agrees that avoiding it is a good idea. By making every aspect of the object mutable, you have no guarantees about what states it can be in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the Keys are the name or identifier of each property.

You may add a `changeValue` method.

This pattern is also known a the `Dynamic Object Design Pattern`.

Example (Pseudocode):

```
void Example()
{
  KeyValueList MyControl = new KeyValueList();
    MyControl->put("id", "MyControl");
    MyControl->put("x", 34);
    MyControl->put("y", 125);
    MyControl->put("height", 200);
    MyControl->put("width", 250);
    MyControl->put("filled", false);

  MyWindow->insertControl(MyControl);
} // void Example()
```

As you may check in the previous example, is common to use a list that store key value items, where there the keys are of `string` types, and cannot be duplicated. The values may be stored as an type specific for each value, like `integer` or `logical`.

Or can be used as `string`, similar to H.T.M.L. or X.M.L. attributes, like this example:

Example (Pseudocode):

```
void Example()
{
  KeyValueList MyControl = new KeyValueList();
    MyControl->put("id", "MyControl");
    MyControl->put("x", "34");
    MyControl->put("y", "125");
    MyControl->put("height", "200");
    MyControl->put("width", "250");
    MyControl->put("filled", "false");

  MyWindow->insertControl(MyControl);
} // void Example()
```

Both, cases are optional.

The example is generic, identifiers and types, can change from library or programming language.

This Design Pattern is commonly used in programming languages that are not Object Oriented, (like "functional" or "procedural"), to emulate objects.

Is also used in Programming Languages that are already Object Oriented, but, the properties are statically designed, and cannot be added or removed at execution.

Cheers.

Comment: Why can't properties be added or removed at execution when using an Object oriented language?

Comment: @erotavlas Some Progr. Langs. are just designed with predefined properties, the programmer can change their value

Comment: BTW thanks a lot for mentioning the alternative name for this pattern (dynamic object pattern)- that alone helped me find some great resources online (along with alternative terms such as dynamic object model and adaptive object model).  I was having a hard time finding any information using the other name (properties pattern)  in my searches.

Comment: That's a useful explanation, of the Properties Pattern as a way to emulate (or add to) objects. But it doesn't really account for why his article is so *enthusiastic* about the Pattern. Especially since his biggest example is the game he wrote (Wyvern), that used Python - which has Objects, Properties, and other things.